# How to chain generics and derived types?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, derived-class

I think I don't understand generics well enough to make my code work, but I can't find an explanation of why it doesn't work.

I have this generic abstract class *Repository* :

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase
{
}
```

I have to instanciate it as *SpecificRepository* :

```
public class SpecificRepository : RepositoryBase
{
}
```

Now, I have this generic abstract class *ManagerBase* which uses a generic type which must derive from *RepositoryBase* :

```
public abstract class ManagerBase<T> where T : RepositoryBase
{
    public T repository;

    protected ManagerBase(T repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```

That I must instanciate with *SpecificManager* :

```
public class SpecificManager : ManagerBase<SpecificRepository>
{
    public SpecificManager(SpecificRepository repostRepository) : base(repostRepository)
    {

    }
}
```

This way, I can have a class deriving from *RepositoryBase* in each class deriving from *ManagerBase*.

But I can't have a *ControllerBase* and a *SpecificController* such as :

```
public class ControllerBase<T> where T : ManagerBase<RepositoryBase>
{
    public T manager;

    protected ControllerBase(T manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
    }
}

public class SpecificController : ControllerBase<SpecificManager>
{
    public SpecificController(SpecificManager manager) : base(manager)
    {

    }
}
```

It seems that I can do :

```
public abstract class ControllerBase<T> where T : ManagerBase<SpecificRepository>
{
    public T manager;

    protected ControllerBase(T manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
    }
}

public class SpecificController : ControllerBase<SpecificManager>
{
    public SpecificController(SpecificManager manager) : base(manager)
    {

    }
}
```

Which doesn't suit my needs though.

Can someone please explain to me what I understand wrong and how am I suppose to proceed to be able to have a *SpecificManager* in each class deriving from *ControllerBase* ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Assuming you have a generic type, `G<T>` (so, with one type argument called `T`). Assume further that you have two more types, `T1` and `T2`, and those types have some form of inheritance relationship between them. Just because they have that inheritance relationship, that does **not** mean that the types `G<T1>` and `G<T2>` have that *same* relationship. In fact, types `G<T1>` and `G<T2>` have *no* inheritance relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, though the syntax is slightly longer:

```
public class ControllerBase<TManager, TRepository>
   where TManager : ManagerBase<TRepository>
   where TRepository : RepositoryBase
/* */

public class SpecificController : ControllerBase<SpecificManager, SpecificRepository>
```